# How to perform sorting operation on list view android?

Tags: android, listview

In my application i am using Custom adapter ans showing the service data to list view. Every thing works fine for me but i want to sort the list view items based on "fare" condition.

Any one help me how to sort my list view based on "fare" (lowest to highest)

My code:

BusData.java :

```
package com.reloadapp.reload.data;

/**
 * Created by user1 on 5/21/2015.
 */
public class BusData
{
    private  String routescheduleid;
    private String companyname;
    private String companyid;
    private String deptime;
    private String arrtime;
    private int fare;
    private String buslabel;
    private String avaliableseats;
    private String bustypename;
    private String difftime;
    boolean ac,non_ac,sleeper,non_slepeer;
    private String pickuproutescheduleid;
    private String pickupname;

    public String getDropoffname() {
        return Dropoffname;
    }

    public void setDropoffname(String dropoffname) {
        Dropoffname = dropoffname;
    }
    public boolean getac() {
        return ac;
    }

    public void setac(boolean ac) {
        this.ac = ac;
    }

    public boolean getnon_ac() {
        return non_ac;
    }

    public void setnon_ac(boolean non_ac) {
        this.non_ac = non_ac;
    }

    public boolean getsleeper() {
        return sleeper;
    }

    public void setsleeper(boolean sleeper) {
        this.sleeper = sleeper;
    }

    public boolean getnon_slepeer() {
        return non_slepeer;
    }

    public void setnon_slepeer(boolean non_slepeer) {
        this.non_slepeer = non_slepeer;
    }

    private String Dropoffname;

        public BusData()
        {

        }

    public String getPickuproutescheduleid() {
        return pickuproutescheduleid;
    }

    public void setPickuproutescheduleid(String pickuproutescheduleid) {
        this.pickuproutescheduleid = pickuproutescheduleid;
    }

    public String getPickupname() {
        return pickupname;
    }

    public void setPickupname(String pickupname) {
        this.pickupname = pickupname;
    }

    public String getDifftime() {
            return difftime;
        }
        public void setDifftime(String difftime) {
            this.difftime = difftime;
        }



    public BusData(String routescheduleid,String companyname,String companyid,String deptime,String arrtime,int fare,String buslabel,String avaliableseats,String bustypename,String difftime)
        {
            this.routescheduleid=routescheduleid;
            this.companyname=companyname;
            this.companyid=companyid;
            this.deptime=deptime;
            this.arrtime=arrtime;
            this.fare=fare;
            this.buslabel=buslabel;
            this.avaliableseats=avaliableseats;
            this.bustypename=bustypename;
            this.difftime=difftime;


        }


        public String getRoutescheduleid() {
            return routescheduleid;
        }
        public void setRoutescheduleid(String routescheduleid) {
            this.routescheduleid = routescheduleid;
        }
        public String getCompanyname() {
            return companyname;
        }
        public void setCompanyname(String companyname) {
            this.companyname = companyname;
        }
        public String getCompanyid() {
            return companyid;
        }
        public void setCompanyid(String companyid) {
            this.companyid = companyid;
        }
        public String getDeptime() {
            return deptime;
        }
        public void setDeptime(String deptime) {
            this.deptime = deptime;
        }
        public String getArrtime() {
            return arrtime;
        }
        public void setArrtime(String arrtime) {
            this.arrtime = arrtime;
        }
        public int getFare() {
            return fare;
        }
        public void setFare(int fare) {
            this.fare = fare;
        }
        public String getBuslabel() {
            return buslabel;
        }
        public void setBuslabel(String buslabel) {
            this.buslabel = buslabel;
        }
        public String getAvaliableseats() {
            return avaliableseats;
        }
        public void setAvaliableseats(String avaliableseats) {
            this.avaliableseats = avaliableseats;
        }
        public String getBustypename() {
            return bustypename;
        }
        public void setBustypename(String bustypename) {
            this.bustypename = bustypename;
        }

}
```

BusAdapter.java:

```
public class BusDataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<BusData> bpData;
    private ArrayList<BusData> arraylist;
    private Activity activity;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    public static String journey_bus;
    public static String rid;
    String travelname, travetime = null;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    //SearchActivity obj=new SearchActivity(journey_bus);


    public BusDataAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<BusData> bpData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.activity = activity;
        this.bpData = bpData;
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);


        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    }

    public void setJourneyBus(String journey_bus) {
        this.journey_bus = journey_bus;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return bpData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return location;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buslistviewitems, null);
            Typeface custom_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/SourceSansPro_Semibold.ttf");
            Typeface custom_regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/SourceSansPro_Light.ttf");
            viewHolder.deptime = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.deptime);

            viewHolder.difftime = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.difftime);
            viewHolder.busfare = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.busfare);

            viewHolder.buslabel = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.buslabel);

            viewHolder.routeid = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.routeid);

            viewHolder.bustypename = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.bustypename);
            viewHolder.availableseat = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.avaliableseats);
            viewHolder.businfo = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.businfo);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.deptime.setText(bpData.get(position).getDeptime() + "-" + bpData.get(position).getArrtime());
        // travetime = bpData.get(position).getDeptime() + "-" + bpData.get(position).getArrtime();
        viewHolder.difftime.setText(bpData.get(position).getDifftime());
        viewHolder.busfare.setText(bpData.get(position).getFare());
        viewHolder.buslabel.setText(bpData.get(position).getBuslabel());
        viewHolder.routeid.setText(bpData.get(position).getRoutescheduleid());

        viewHolder.bustypename.setText(bpData.get(position).getBustypename());
        // travelname = bpData.get(position).getBuslabel();
        viewHolder.availableseat.setText(bpData.get(position).getAvaliableseats() + "Seats");


        if (bpData.get(position).getAvaliableseats().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
            viewHolder.availableseat.setText("Sold Out");

        } else {
            viewHolder.availableseat.setText(bpData.get(position).getAvaliableseats() + "Seats");
        }
  class ViewHolder {
        TextView difftime, deptime, busfare, buslabel, routeid, bustypename, availableseat;
        LinearLayout businfo;
        //Button businfo;
    }}
```

FromtoActivity.java:

```
public class FromtoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<BusData> bdata = new ArrayList<BusData>();
    ArrayList<BusData> filter_list = new ArrayList<BusData>();
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fromto);
 Intent intent = getIntent();
        json_object = intent.getStringExtra("json_objcet");
busdata();
}

   public void busdata() {
        try {

            bdata.clear();
            travel_list.clear();
            filter_list.clear();
            JSONObject result = new JSONObject(json_object);

            JSONObject Data = result.getJSONObject("Data");
            routearray = Data.getJSONArray("Route");
            for (int i = 0; i < routearray.length(); i++) {


                //  String companyid = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("CompanyId");
                CompanyName = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("CompanyName");
                String deptime = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("DepTime");
                routeScheduleId = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("RouteScheduleId");
                String arrtime = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ArrTime");
            /* String dtDeparture = "2014-12-15T13:30:00";
             String dtArrival = "2014-12-15T23:00:00";*/
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

                Date dateDeparture = format.parse(deptime);
                Date dateArrival = format.parse(arrtime);
                dateArrival.compareTo(dateDeparture);
                long diff = dateArrival.getTime() - dateDeparture.getTime();
                long arrivaltime = dateArrival.getTime();
                arrivaldate = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(new Date(arrivaltime));

                long departuretime = dateDeparture.getTime();
                depardate = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(new Date(departuretime));
              /* Log.v("TAG_realarrtime",""+arrivaldate);
               Log.v("TAG_realdeptime",""+depardate);
             */

                long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diff);

                long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff) - hours * 60;
                // System.out.println(hours + "." + minutes + "hrs");
                msg = hours + "." + minutes + "hrs";
                fare = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("Fare");
                hasac = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HasAC");
                hasnac = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HasNAC");
                hasseater = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HasSeater");
                hassleeper = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HasSleeper");
                String isvolvo = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("IsVolvo");
                buslabel = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("BusLabel");
                avaliableseats = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("AvailableSeats");
                bustypename = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("BusTypeName");


                BusData bs = new BusData();
                // bs.setCompanyname(CompanyName);
                //bs.setCompanyid(companyid);
                bs.setFare(fare);
                bs.setBuslabel(CompanyName);
                bs.setBustypename(bustypename);
                bs.setAvaliableseats(avaliableseats);
                bs.setArrtime(arrivaldate);
                bs.setDeptime(depardate);
                bs.setDifftime(msg);

                bs.setac(routearray.getJSONObject(i).getBoolean("HasAC"));
                bs.setnon_ac(routearray.getJSONObject(i).getBoolean("HasNAC"));
                bs.setsleeper(routearray.getJSONObject(i).getBoolean("HasSleeper"));
                bs.setnon_slepeer(routearray.getJSONObject(i).getBoolean("HasSeater"));
                bs.setRoutescheduleid(routeScheduleId);

                bdata.add(bs);

                if (!travel_list.contains(bdata.get(i).getBuslabel()))
                    travel_list.add(bdata.get(i).getBuslabel());


            }


            adapter = new BusDataAdapter(this, bdata);
            fromto.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.setJourneyBus(date_bus);
            filter_list.addAll(bdata);

            adapter = new BusDataAdapter(this, filter_list);
            fromto.setAdapter(adapter);
        /* adapter.setrouteid(routeScheduleId);
        */
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Pass the ListView an already sorted Adapter.

Comment: I guess you need to arrange the `ArrayList` items before adding it to the adapter, or arrange and call `notifyDatasetChanged`. Arranging the item views is impractical. However, arranging `ArrayList` based on attribute is much more feasible.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/fjfish/3024308

Answer (score 2):

You should sort the list before call adapter to list the data.

```
  Collections.sort(bdata, new Comparator<BusData>() {
                public int compare(BusData o1, BusData o2) {
                    return o2.getFare().compareTo(o1.getFare());
                }
            });
            for(BusData busData:bdata)
            {
                Log.e("Fare : ",busData.getFare());
            }
```

After sorting completed call Adapter to list the data:

```
adapter = new BusDataAdapter(this, bdata);
            fromto.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.setJourneyBus(date_bus);
            filter_list.addAll(bdata);

            adapter = new BusDataAdapter(this, filter_list);
            fromto.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: totally ! i was just writing a similar approach but you were faster :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collections.sort method for this..
  Do like this...

```
 Collections.sort(filterlist, new Comparator<bData>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(bData lhs, bData rhs) {
                            return (lhs.getFair() > rhs.getFair()) ? -1 : (lhs.getFair() > rhs.getFair()) ? 1 : 0;
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use comparator api in android.

```
Comparator<BusData> comparator=new Comparator<BusData>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(final BusData lhs, final BusData rhs) {
                return lhs.getFare().equals(rhs.getFare());
            }
        };

Collections.sort(busDataList,comparator);
```

then your list will be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give already sorted collection of buses to your adapter. Adapter shouldn't be responsible for sorting and ListView as well.
Try this:

```
Collections.sort(bdata, new Comparator<BusData>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(BusData lhs, BusData rhs) {
        return lhs.getFare() > rhs.getFare();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Comparator and sort the list

```
  class FareComparator implements Comparator{  
   public int Compare(Object o1,Object o2){  
   BusData s1=(BusData)o1;  
    BusData s2=(BusData)o2;  

    if(s1.fare==s2.fare)  
    return 0;  
     else if(s1.fare>s2.fare)  
    return -1;  
    else  
    return 1;   
    }  
 }
```

and use

```
Collections.sort(bdata,new FareComparator());
```

before the

```
  adapter = new BusDataAdapter(this, bdata);
```